# Why do literals not const by default?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, constants, lazy-evaluation

If F# encourages to write immutable eagerly evaluated data, why did F# not enforce simple let bindings to be `const` by default?

I need to explicitly write `[<Literal>]` attributes. For example:

```
module ConstVsStaticReadOnly =

    [<Literal>]
    let ConstInt32 = 1

    [<Literal>]
    let ConstString = "A" + "B" + "C"

    let staticReadOnlyBoolean = true
```

Comment: "Simple bindings" (as any other bindings) of values are compiled as static properties. Silently making some of them properties and some constants would introduce an inconsistency that would make automated processing of the code (e.g. analyzers, transpilers, etc.) that much harder.

Comment: I find it more convenient to write `let [<Literal>] A = 1`, which also helps prevent code drift.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Can you tell me why is it harder to handler `const`? For example, I'm using Resharper, which uses its own analyzer and not .NET roslyn, it would remind me if a `static readonly` can be refactored as `const`.

Comment: Handling constants is not harder than handling properties. Handling both of them is harder than handling any one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use a `const` in .NET, all references to it are replaced by its value at compile time.

It sounds fine until you realize it is not limited to the assembly where the constant is defined. Other assemblies referencing it will also copy the value of the constant at the time of compilation.

You can see the results in a simple example:

Create a new F# Library project with a single module

```
module ConstTest 

let [<Literal>] ConstInt = 1
let NotConstInt = ConstInt
```

Then a console app with a reference to the library

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A %A" ConstTest.ConstInt ConstTest.NotConstInt
    0
```

When run, it prints `1 1` - as expected.

Now modify the constant in the library

```
module ConstTest 

let [<Literal>] ConstInt = 2
let NotConstInt = ConstInt
```

Build the library (but not the console app!), copy the dll to the console app folder and run the app. It prints `1 2`. Quite a surprise if you're not aware of this behavior.

Once you create a public constant, it should **never** change. That's why compilers will not create constants implicitly.